# Javascript only active when viewing from specific directory

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a CMS and editing the theme is extremely complicated =/
I want to include a navigation bar that is active when a user is in certain directories.
This code will be on the overall theme file that will be on all webpages. <-- limitation I am working around

Example

www.dumbysite.com/products/ <-- Navigation bar is shown

www.dumbysite.com/products/subcat1/ <-- navigation bar is still showing

www.dumbysite.com/collection/ <-- not active

What's the trick to getting something like this done?

Comment: Are you using a server side language such as PHP? This would easily allow you to include a template via a file but only for the specific pages that you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var dir = window.location.pathname.split('/',2);
  if (dir[1] == "products") {
    // do something...
  }
}();
</script>
```

Comment: beautiful. Short and sweet. thanks